# How to show Created By "NAME" using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, timestamp

I am new to MongoDB, so I was wondering if there any way to show the name of created by or modified by XYZ user? I want it in my application to display the name who created or modified something.

Comment: This might be a better question if you included more information with it. Be as specific as you can. E.g. "I am saving `posts` to a MongoDB collection `posts`, which include `title` and `text`. I retrieve these on /api/posts endpoint in my Angular app. How can I add audit data to my collection - who created or modified it, and when. I would also like to show this information on frontend.".
Additionally, if you split up the question into those parts (1. how to save and retreive this info from DB, and 2. How to display such info) your questions would be more likely to get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for this info when structuring your data model. E.g. let's say you're writing posts to the `posts` collection, and want to add the post author from `authors` collection.

Now, the simplest way to do this is to have this data directly embedded in your `post` document. E.g. for creation data we use [insert](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#insert), something like this:

```
// posts.service.js
function save(postData, userData) {
  // We return a Promise here
  return db.posts.insert({
    title: postData.title,
    text: postData.text,
    published: true,
    // now comes your audit data
    createdBy: user.username,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  });
}
module.exports = { save };
```

You use it like this, ie. in your /posts API controller:

```
// ... other stuff then:
const postsService = require('./posts.service');
route.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
  postsService.save({
      title: req.body.title,
      text: req.body.text,
}, req.user)
  // Handle response and error.
  .then(response => res.json(response))
  .catch(error => next(error));
```

And for updating a post, you'd add this to `posts.service.js` (using [update](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#update)):

```
// posts.service
// ...after your *save* function above
function update(postId, postData, userData) {
  return db.posts.update({
      id: postId,
    }{
      title: postData.title,
      text: postData.text,
      published: true,
      // now comes your audit data
      modifiedBy: user.username,
      modifiedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    });
}
// update module exports:
module.exports = { save, update };
```

Now, on your controller, add the route to handle updates:

```
// ... after the creation route
route.put('/posts/:postId', function(req, res, next) {
  postsService.update(req.params.postId, {
      title: req.body.title,
      text: req.body.text,
}, req.user)
  // Handle response and error.
  .then(response => res.json(response))
  .catch(error => next(error));
```

Now, other ways to do this can mean you only include reference (ObjectId) of whomever modified the data. Or maybe more info.

But smarter and easier thing to do would be to use something like mongoose for handling your data, and then use a plugin that does all this automatically. Something like this: https://github.com/taptaptech/mongoose-audit.

You could look for something similar at npm: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mongoose%20audit.

What these things do is they add pre-save hooks to your documents and in those hooks the audit data is tracked. So you can use something finished, or you can look at what these packages do and try to replicate the functionality - better if this is a hobby project and you wanna learn how things work.

Now, how do you show this information in your frontend is likely good for a new question, as you specify no information about any of the software/packages you're using.

Answer (score 0):

you should just write it down in your db upon edit/create, there is no build in functionality for this.